# .NET 4.0 project on IIS 7.0

Tags: .net, iis-7

We have an IIS 7.0 server running a .NET framework 3.5, MVC2 application.  We now need to run a .NET Framework 4.0, MVC3 app on this same server and have both apps run from the same server.

Whenever I try to browse the 4.0/MVC3 website after deploying it, I get a 404.0 error that it can't find C:\inetpub\wwwroot\MYNEWAPP\Error

This project works perfectly fine on a local machine.  I feel like I've been down every path (including the ones on this website), but still can't get it fixed.  The older website on this same server still works fine.  I believe I have the pool set up correctly also.

Where can I look next?  I can't find permission problems or anything like that.

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: is the app pool set correctly?

Comment: Is .NET 4.0 installed and IIS setup to use it? (go to the 4.0 framework folder and execute `aspnet_regiis` if not).

Comment: I did run the aspnet_regiis and I believe app pool is set up correctly.  It is using the 4.0 app pool

Comment: I am actually using asp.net 4.0 application pool whereas my working app is using DefaultAppPool

Answer (score 2):

.net 3.5 and 4 can co-exist just fine.  However, you need to make sure the worker process is set to use the correct framework.  .net 4 requires the 4.0 runtime and .net 3.5 requires the v2.0 runtime.